# Crypto class on release site

Tags: c#, security, hash

Lately I run across the **System.Web.Helpers.Crypto** class.

working with the **Crypto.HashPassword** function seems like a very easy/simple solution. but I am not sure about this sentense (from msdn):

> The password hash is generated with the RFC 2898 algorithm using a
>   128-bit salt, a 256-bit subkey, and **1000 iterations**. The format of the
>   generated hash bytestream is {0x00, salt, subkey}, which is base-64
>   encoded before it is returned.

so my questions:

1) Is it ok to use this class on a production/release site?

2) Does the limitiation of 1000 iterations reveal the web site to secure problems.?

3) if so, is there a simple way to overcome this limitation?

I know that calling `Crypto.HashPassword(MyPlainText)` will automatically generate salt and hash them together, but what if i also concatenate a random salt with my plain text like this code:

`var myAdditionSalt=Crypto.GenerateSalt();`
 `Crypto.HashPassword(MyPlainText+myAdditionSalt)`

and also store **myAdditionSalt** in database.
will it increase security?

Comment: 1000 is pretty low. I prefer 20000 with .net's build in implementation, and even larger values when using a decent implementation.

Comment: that is why i don't understand the limit of 1000 iterations. did they meant it to be used on release site or only for development?

Comment: why vote down by the way?

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Is it ok to use this class on a production/release site?

As with any system, the effectiveness of security controls is a function of the resources an adversary would devote to compromising the controls.  If the consequence of a compromise is minimal, fewer iterations may be appropriate, even in a production environment.

It should be added that password repositories have intrinsic value to attackers, since a user may reuse a password across multiple services.  In some scenarios, the passwords themselves will require greater protection than the resources the credentials protect.

> 2) Does the limitiation of 1000 iterations reveal the web site to secure problems.?

I would suggest reviewing the question and responses [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3959/recommended-of-iterations-when-using-pkbdf2-sha256).  1,000 iterations is the minimum recommended in RFC 2898 (published in 2000).  In a [2012 study (PDF)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&ved=0CFoQFjAG&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.emsec.rub.de%2Fmedia%2Fcrypto%2Fveroeffentlichungen%2F2013%2F01%2F29%2Fesorics_pbkdf2.pdf&ei=F6SFUpHpDPPb4AO3uoG4Cg&usg=AFQjCNHrgLxEMgIbaEcBysmRJIZv3OwTjA), Durmuth et al concluded that "we do not consider it sufficient for a secure system to run at a constant (minimum) amount of 1000 hash iterations in the lifetime of an application or a system, as defined by RFC 2898 for PBKDF2," recommending instead a dynamic iteration count lower-bounded by available computational resources.

> 3) Is there a simple way to overcome this limitation?

While slightly more complicated, you can use the [`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes(v=vs.110).aspx) class in the `System.Cryptography` namespace directly.  This class provides a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes(v=vs.110).aspx) that accepts the password, hash, and number of iterations as parameters.  (See [here](http://csharptest.net/470/another-example-of-how-to-store-a-salted-password-hash/) for a functional implementation example.)

> 4) will [concatenating an additional salt with the password] increase security?

In this special case, the additional salt will effectively introduce entropy (complexity) to the user password, as though the user entered a more complex password.  Since the additional salt would need to be stored for password verification, the added security gain would potentially be negated if the attacker has access to this second salt.

This said, cryptographic specifications are highly-sensitive to algorithmic changes, and deviating from the specification can introduce vulnerabilities that can be exploited through cryptoanalysis.  Best practice for strengthening security would be to increase the number of iterations (which RFC 299 endorses), rather than introduce nonstandard enhancements.